NullPointException occured when I use any method in ReportPrint class
I tried to store reports informations in reports object as I did in GuitarStock class.
In ReportPrint class, System.out.println(reports[i].getDeleteReports())
is properly worked in writeReports() but in  printStockReport() System.out.println(reports[i].getDeleteReports()) getters don't work.
I really want to solve this problem
this class define report data attribute as a object
class ReportData {
    private String addReports;
    private String deleteReports;
    private String editReports;
    private final String sellReports;

    ReportData(String addReports, String deleteReports, String editReports, String sellReports) {
        this.addReports = addReports;
        this.editReports = editReports;
        this.deleteReports = deleteReports;
        this.sellReports = sellReports;
    }

    public String getAddReports() {
        return addReports;
    }

    public String getDeleteReports() {
        return deleteReports;
    }

    public String getEditReports() {
        return editReports;
    }

    public String getSellReport() {
        return sellReports;
    }
    public void setAddReports(String addReports){
        this.addReports = addReports;
    }

    public void setDeleteReports(String deleteReports) {
        this.deleteReports = deleteReports;
    }

    public void setEditReports(String editReports) {
        this.editReports = editReports;
    }
}

this class works by get information from (deleteStock, addStock, editStock, sellStock) methods in GuitarStock class
I think storing data doesn't work between GuitarStock class and ReportData class
I guess it could be a problem in method chaining. I could happen in the squence, in GuitarStock class,
ReportPrint report = new ReportPrint(); counld be a problem. because initReports method in ReportPrint class can called again
class ReportPrint{
    private ReportData[] reports = new ReportData[10];
    private final CurrentTime currentTime = new CurrentTime();
    void initReports() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            reports[i] = new ReportData("%^", "%^", "%^", "%^");
        }
    }

    public void printStockReport() {
        System.out.println("Added Stock:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (!"%^".equals(reports[i].getAddReports())) {
                String s = reports[i].getAddReports();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Deleted Stock:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (!"%^".equals(reports[i].getDeleteReports())) {
                String s = reports[i].getDeleteReports();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Edited Stock:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (!"%^".equals(reports[i].getEditReports())) {
                String s = reports[i].getEditReports();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
    public void printSellReport() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (!"%^".equals(reports[i].getEditReports())) {
                String s = reports[i].getSellReport();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }

    public void writeAddReports(String contents) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if ("%^".equals(reports[i].getAddReports())) {
                String s = currentTime.getCurrentTime() + contents + " added.";
                reports[i].setAddReports(s);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void writeDeleteReports(String contents) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if ("%^".equals(reports[i].getDeleteReports())) {
                String s = currentTime.getCurrentTime() + contents + " deleted.";
                reports[i].setDeleteReports(s);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void writeEditReports(String beforeContent, String currentContent) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if ("%^".equals(reports[i].getEditReports())) {
                String s = currentTime.getCurrentTime() + beforeContent + "\n" + currentContent + " edited.";
                reports[i].setEditReports(s);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void writeSellReport(String contents) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if ("%^".equals(reports[i].getSellReport())) {
                String s = currentTime.getCurrentTime() + contents + " sold.";
                reports[i].setEditReports(s);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}



ReportPrint report = new ReportPrint(); counld be a problem. because initReports method in ReportPrint class can called again I suspect you were close to seeing the problem. I see no evidence that you ever call initReports().

Does this answer your question? What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?


Can you share the stacktrace with the exception? 2) GuitarStock isn't shown, so we don't know what you're referring to 3) ReportData has a constructor. Why not ReportPrint class that calls initReports?


Finally, I solved this problem now.
The reason of error was the line "ReportPrint report = new ReportPrint();" in GuitarStock class.
When any methods call this property "report", initReport() method worked automatically.
As a result reports parameters are always "null".
As a result occured NullPointerException.
As a result I erased "ReportPrint report = new ReportPrint();" in GuitarStock class.
I made void methods in GuitarStock class to String.
and made "print.writeEditReports(editStock);"
it works! thank you.
